# Triangle inequality and homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, analysis, inequality

Here is my situation: I have two homomorphisms $f$ and $g$ from a group $A$ into the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. I know that they are 'close' on a subset $B \subseteq A$. More formally there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $|f(b)-g(b)| < \epsilon$ for all $b \in B$.

Now let $a \in A$ be fixed. I am wondering if there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(ab) - g(ab)|<\delta$ for all $b \in B$. That is are $f$ and $g$ also 'close' on $aB$? I know that $|f(ab)-g(ab)| = |f(a)f(b)-g(a)g(b)|$ and I feel like I have seen a triangle inequality argument that can be applied to things of this form in the past. However, I do not remember the details and I have been unable to reconstruct it myself. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have 'mixing' of both $f$ and $g$ and elements $a$ and $b$ is why life is hard right now; adding and subtracting something like $f(a) g(b)$ or $f(b) g(a)$ can make it easier:

\begin{align*}
|f(a)f(b) - g(a)g(b)| &\le |f(a) f(b) - f(a) g(b)| + |f(a) g(b) - g(a) g(b)| \\
&= |f(a)| |f(b) - g(b)| + |g(b)| |f(a) - g(a)| \\
&< |f(a)| \epsilon + |g(b)| |f(a) - g(a)|
\end{align*}

So now, if you can control the size of $g(b)$, then you can control everything. Alternatively (or rather, equivalently), by inserting $f(b) g(a)$, then control on $f(b)$ gives you overall control.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I can control the size of $g(b)$ so this works perfectly.

Comment: You're very welcome - glad I could help. This style of argumentation, where you 'unmix' terms by adding and subtracting something complicated is amazingly useful.